# Web.Config Debug/Release

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I know that web.config in Visual Studio 2010 provides the ability to switch from databases from Debug mode to Release mode.

**Here is my Web.Release.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Testing1" connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**Here is my Web.Debug.config code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Live1" connectionString="Data Source=Live;Initial Catalog=LiveDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**And this is my Web.config code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433 -->
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
       <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
       </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
       <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
       </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
       <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
       </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I publish my project there is nothing showing in my Web.config file.it Is not showing my Live Database connection string?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The web.config transforms that are part of Visual Studio 2010 use XSLT in order to "transform" the current web.config file into its .Debug or .Release version.

In your .Debug/.Release files, you need to add the following parameter in your connection string fields:

```
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
```

This will cause each connection string line to find the matching name and update the attributes accordingly.

*Note: You won't have to worry about updating your providerName parameter in the transform files, since they don't change.*

Here's an example from one of my apps. Here's the web.config file section:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="EAF" connectionString="[Test Connection String]" />
</connectionString>
```

And here's the web.config.release section doing the proper transform:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="EAF" connectionString="[Prod Connection String]"
           xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
           xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>
```

*One added note: Transforms only occur when you publish the site, not when you simply run it with F5 or CTRL+F5. If you need to run an update against a given config locally, you will have to manually change your Web.config file for this.*

For more details you can see the MSDN documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Can you add a note that this happens in publish time NOT F5 time to the answer? Apparently I've had this correct for 2 hours but didn't realize that.

Comment: How can I make this work with Visual Studio Online Continuous Build? I want it to transform my Web.Config during build and deploy to Azure.

Comment: @RosdiKasim - I'm not sure if this will match up 100% for Visual Studio online, but when I need to deploy a specific project (if I have multiple) or use a different build (and thus transform) I specify things directly in the Azure website instance. Here's some details I wrote up on that a while back: http://www.freshconsulting.com/2-alternate-configurations-for-windows-azure-deployment/

Comment: here is a link to MSDN that descirbe this in details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Only for remember: 
the line `<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">` must be only in web.debug.config and web.release.config. But not in web.config.

Comment: Your added note regarding running the site in VS via F5 vs. publishing was very helpful to me.

Comment: @Paul - For a "F5 time" (=build) solution look at Dennis's great answer.

Comment: @Dillie-O What about the **web.config.release section**? You do not post it here :(

Comment: @Jason - The web.config.release section actually has the transform, you just have to scroll all the way to the right to see where the XDT attributes are. I probably could have made things a little shorter to emphasize the important parts.

Comment: @Dillie-O The shorter the more less clarifiier.So, it is better tı edit I think.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible using `ConfigTransform` build target available as a Nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform/

> All "web.*****.config" transform files will be transformed and output as a
>   series of "web.*.config.transformed" files in the build output
>   directory regardless of the chosen build configuration.
>
> The same applies to "app.*.config" transform files in non-web
>   projects.

and then adding the following target to your `*.csproj`.

```
<Target Name="TransformActiveConfiguration" Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)/Web.$(Configuration).config')" BeforeTargets="Compile" >
    <TransformXml Source="$(ProjectDir)/Web.Config" Transform="$(ProjectDir)/Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(TargetDir)/Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Posting an answer as this is the first Stackoverflow post that appears in Google on the subject.

Comment: This great method worked perfectly for me. However I did not have to install the ConfigTransform NuGet you mentioned (which has the effect of always transforming all configurations). I just copied the target snippet in your answer to the csproj. Then when I set the active build configuration on Visual Studio (e.g. change it to debug) the transform is done accordingly when I build the solution.

Answer (score 5):

To make the transform work in development (using F5 or CTRL + F5) I drop ctt.exe (https://ctt.codeplex.com/) in the packages folder (packages\ConfigTransform\ctt.exe).

Then I register a pre- or post-build event in Visual Studio...

```
$(SolutionDir)packages\ConfigTransform\ctt.exe source:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.config" transform:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.$(ConfigurationName).config" destination:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.config"
$(SolutionDir)packages\ConfigTransform\ctt.exe source:"$(ProjectDir)web.config" transform:"$(ProjectDir)web.$(ConfigurationName).config" destination:"$(ProjectDir)web.config"
```

For the transforms I use SlowCheeta VS extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

Comment: In order to preserve white spaces (prevents the transformed config to be on one line) add preservewhitespace indent IndentChars:"  " to the command line. `$(SolutionDir)packages\ConfigTransform\ctt.exe source:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.config" transform:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.$(ConfigurationName).config" destination:"$(ProjectDir)connectionStrings.config" preservewhitespace indent IndentChars:"  "`

Answer (score 4):

If your are going to replace ***all of the connection strings*** with news ones for production environment, you can simply replace all connection strings with production ones using this syntax:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <!-- production environment config --->
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Testing1" connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
....
```

Information for this answer are brought from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416118/1080355) and [this blog post](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings).

**notice**: As others explained already, this setting will apply only when application publishes not when running/debugging it (by hitting F5).