# How to select Webconfig to use?

Tags: asp.net

Say I have two sets of web configuration, where do I put the selection code?

I want my code be able to interchangeable between two sets of configurations

Comment: Are these configuration files for separate environments or do you need separate configuration files for the same environment? Could you please care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Do you want to switch configurations at compile time or run-time?

Comment: Preferably, I would like to have two separate configuration files for the same environment.

And to make it debug friendly, I would like to switch the config at run-time if it's possible.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What sections do you need to change? I would guess it is related to either connectionStrings and/or AppSettings

Comment: I want to maintain the old authentication method while developing the new one. So I can interchange between them. So, not only the connectionStrings and/or AppSettings are involved.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want web.config files like this.

[image]

It basically transform **Web.Config** based on the selection.

If it is what you want, there are lot of questions in SO regarding that.

[Web.Config Debug/Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811305/web-config-debug-release)

[Web Deployment: Web.Config Transformation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)

Comment: I don't really want to publish, so transform is not suitable for my case. Is there a way to select web config at building?