# Different AutoLogin URL in Debug and Release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to simplify this in one single line of code?

Thanks.

```
public static string BuildAutoLoginUrl(string username)
{
#if DEBUG
   return @"/Account/AutoLogin?key=" + GetAutoLoginKey(username);
#else
   return @"http://www.domain.com/Account/AutoLogin?key=" + GetAutoLoginKey(username);
#endif
}
```

Comment: In release mode, is `www.domain.com` the URL the auto-login request is coming from? If so, why do you not just leave it as the first line only, what is the problem with doing that?

Comment: Why not read it from config, which can use transformation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811305/web-config-debug-release

Comment: @Yahya: I know transformations but the question is about simplifying this in one single line of code.

Comment: @Alberto that'd be just `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginURL"]`. Why would you want to hardcode URL?

Comment: Why do this at all? There is a utility function available to test local url

Comment: @Mark: What utility function?

Comment: @Alberto   Url.IsLocalUrl

Comment: @Mark: Interesting but why I can't use something like `@"~/Account/AutoLogin?key="` for both instead?

Answer (score -1):

### No

According to [the documentation for C# preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) it states the following:

> A preprocessor directive must be the only instruction on a line.

Therefore the answer is no, it's not possible to reduce the code down to one line.