# Web.config debug/release, changing a value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform

Currently my web.config file has this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

I want requireSSL to be "true" in release and "false" in debug. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config does not support conditional statements.

This is typically handled in deployment. You can use transformation files.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Could you please write how to do this for my example?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Web.Release.config file:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)"/>
```

Here's a handy tool from AppHarbor for testing the results of your transformations: https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you are looking for

[Web.Config Debug/Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811305/web-config-debug-release)

Please check this one

xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"