# Create a conditional statement to create a tag on web config

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to base on debugging or release mode to create a tag on web config.

And I have tried these below codes, but they didn't work.

```
    #if !DEBUG
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
     #Endif
    <hostingEnvironment  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```

Neither of them worked.

Comment: does this answer your question? [Web.Config Debug/Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811305/web-config-debug-release)

Comment: I dont have two webconfig.I have just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it for config files. I suggest that you use a configuration file transformations.

Check out this documentation for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd465318.aspx